Showing a GtkWindow as dialog from XML UI file
This is the XML part of the GtkWindow:
<object class="GtkWindow" id="ItemEditorDlg">
<property name="transient-for">toplevel</property>
<property name="destroy-with-parent">true</property>
<property name="hide-on-close">true</property>
<property name="modal">true</property>
</object>

This is part of my MainWindow header file:
class MyMainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow {
private:
 std::unique_ptr<ytdlp4mm::ItemEditorDlg> m_ItemEditorDlg; // right way?
public:
    MyMainWindow(BaseObjectType*, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>&, Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application>&);
protected:
 void on_action_editor(int);
};

Now the method:
void MyMainWindow::on_action_editor(int type) {
  if (!m_ItemEditorDlg) {
    m_ItemEditorDlg.reset(Gtk::Builder::get_widget_derived<ItemEditorDlg>(m_refBuilder, "ItemEditorDlg", *this, type));
    m_ItemEditorDlg->signal_hide().connect([]() {
      std::cout << "ItemEditorDlg hide\n";
    });
  }
  m_ItemEditorDlg->present();
}

And the ItemEditorDlg source code:
ItemEditorDlg::ItemEditorDlg(BaseObjectType* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& refBuilder, Gtk::ApplicationWindow&, int) :
 Gtk::Window(cobject),
  m_refBuilder(refBuilder) {
}

As you can see on_action_editor call the window as dialog. I read some example codes and ran into std::unique_ptr to manage m_ItemEditorDlg lifecycle. My question or doubt is if this an accurate approach to avoid memory leaks while show/hide m_ItemEditorDlg multiple times.
